# Cannot open my application through Appium script

Tags: uwp, appium, winapp

I am trying to automate my application and it is Windows 10 app. I am using winapp driver and Appium to automate this.

When the script tries to launch the application I encounter the below error.

Request your help in this regard please.

PS - I tried to open windows calculator and it opened well. I couldn't open my application. I am trying this on the real device. When I try to run in from my local laptop it works well.

> [WinAppDriver] [STDOUT] {"status":100,"value":{"error":"invalid
>   argument","message":"Value does not fall within the expected range."}}
>   [W3C] Matched W3C error code 'invalid argument' to
>   InvalidArgumentError [WinAppDriver] Deleting WinAppDriver session
>
> [BaseDriver] Event 'newSessionStarted' logged at 1541083278470
>   (07:41:18 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time)) [W3C] Encountered internal
>   error running command: InvalidArgumentError: Value does not fall
>   within the expected range. [W3C] at errorFromW3CJsonCode (C:\Program
>   Files
>   (x86)\Appium\resources\app\node_modules\appium\node_modules\appium-base-driver\lib\protocol\errors.js:802:25)

Environment
Appium version - 1.9.1
WinApp Version - 1.1
Java client - 6.1
OS - Windows 10

The parameters that I specify to open my app are:

```
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities(); 
capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.DEVICE_NAME,"WindowsPC"); 
capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_NAME,"Windows"); 
capabilities.setCapability("app", "Msg_ac40azsqrb5g7!App"); 
capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.NEW_COMMAND_TIMEOUT, "60"); 
capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.AUTOMATION_NAME, "Appium"); 
msfSession = new WindowsDriver(new URL("127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities);
```

Comment: What are the arguments you are specifying to open app?

Comment: Hi Pankaj,
The below is the parameters that I specify to open my app
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.DEVICE_NAME,"WindowsPC");
capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_NAME,"Windows");
capabilities.setCapability("app", "Msg_ac40azsqrb5g7!App");
capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.NEW_COMMAND_TIMEOUT, "60");
capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.AUTOMATION_NAME, "Appium");
msfSession = new WindowsDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities);

Comment: can u change name of app ? app", "Msg_ac40azsqrb5g7!App  or try to give appname in single quotes